# FileUtils.ListFilesAndDirs non recursively not listing directories

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to get all directories and files in a directory non recursively but it seems to only list the files and the current directory. It doesn't list the immediate subdirectories.

I am doing:

```
Collection<File> srcFiles = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File("foo/bar/baz"), TrueFileFilter.TRUE, null);
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you need to achieve it using the apache-commons FileUtils class?

Comment: Not necessarily, I just thought it would have been the easiest way, if you know of another way that is fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Java NIO:

```
Files.list(Paths.get("foo/bar/baz")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```